# Moving windows between GNU screen sessions

Tags: gnu-screen, window, session, window-manager

Is there a way to move windows between different screen sessions?

For example lets say I have this scenario:

```
screen -S screen1
vim *.cpp
C-a d
screen -S screen2
```

Is there any way to move my shell containing my vim session from screen1 to screen2?

Comment: i don't think so, but i'm not much of a *screen* guru.  interesting question, +1.

Comment: found a discussion on the screen mailing list - http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/screen-users/2008-04/msg00009.html - it's not possible at the moment and a 'nightmare' to implement apparently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use injcode to move a process between ttys.
To move process with PID run in target screen window:

```
$ injcode -m retty PID
```

However when you close the parent Screen session, moved processes will also terminate.

Edit:
I was wrong, it works. Everything is described [here](http://blog.habets.pp.se/2009/03/Moving-a-process-to-another-terminal).
Suppose you want to move "htop" and only one instance is running:

```
$ injcode -m retty $(pgrep htop)
$ pkill -SIGSTOP htop
$ pkill -SIGCONT htop
```

then on the previous shell type:

```
$ disown
```